# smbd has to be restarted on boot

Tags: cron, server-message-block

For some reason, smbd never seems to start correctly when the server starts. Simply calling /etc/init.d/smbd restart works great, but is there a way that I can either fix the underlying issue or add /etc/init.d/smbd restart to a cron? I just can't seem to figure out how to add the restart parameter.

```
Jul 24 08:56:33 server smbd[1029]: [2012/07/24 08:56:33.898006,  0] smbd/server.c:1107(main)
Jul 24 08:56:33 server smbd[1029]:   standard input is not a socket, assuming -D option
Jul 24 08:56:34 server smbd[1277]: [2012/07/24 08:56:34.099875,  0] printing/print_cups.c:110(cups_connect)
Jul 24 08:56:34 server smbd[1277]:   Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
Jul 24 08:56:34 server smbd[1029]: [2012/07/24 08:56:34.099980,  0] printing/print_cups.c:487(cups_async_callback)
Jul 24 08:56:34 server smbd[1029]:   failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: On what OS do you work? When do the log messages you posted appear?

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure smbd is starting after cups.

Comment: How can I check/alter that?

Comment: Under Linux (assuming sysv-style init, not systemd) the number prefixing the init script in /etc/rc[0-S].d/ indicates the order it starts in.